# While writing into a file , Where intermediate data stored in between fopen() and fclose()?

Tags: c, fopen, file-handling, fclose

Below is a small program which takes information from user and write it into a file `teacher.txt`.
I am using only one `array q2[30]` for taking input and writing into a file using `fprintf()`.
But when i want to enter more teacher then again loop will execute but at this time `fclose()` will not appear
so data will not be write/save(don't know) into file also previous value of q2 get erased/overwrite with new input.
So in this case where data is stored/write by `fprintf()`.Because when i manually open `teacher.txt` before `fclose()` there is no any new data.

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream.h> 

int main()
{
 system("cls");
 int yoe;
 char cond[]="yes";char q2[30];

 FILE *p;
 p = fopen("teacher.txt","a+"); //opening file in reading + appending mode
 printf("\nDo you want to add more Teacher ? (yes/no)\n");
 gets(q2);
 fflush(stdin);
 if(!strcmp(q2,cond))
 {
     do
     {
         printf("\nEnter Teacher's Name\n");
         gets(q2);
         fprintf(p,"\n!%s!",q2);
         printf("Enter Teacher's Qualifications\n");
         fflush(stdin);
         gets(q2);
         fprintf(p,"%s!",q2);
         printf("Enter Teacher's year of experience (0-30)\n");
         fflush(stdin);
         scanf("%d",&yoe);
         fprintf(p,"%d!",yoe);
         printf("Enter Teacher's Mobile number(id) [Should be of 10 digits]\n");
         fflush(stdin);
         gets(q2);
         fprintf(p,"%s!",q2);
         printf("\nDo you want to add more Teacher ? (yes/no)\n");
         fflush(stdin);
         gets(q2);
     }while(!strcmp(q2,cond));  // condition to check , if user want to add more Teacher , if yes then loop will execute again.
     fclose(p);  // when user enter 'no' then only fclose will appear.
 }
 fclose(p);printf("\nPress any key to return to Admin menu\n");
 getch();
 system("pause");
}
```

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behavior, and DO NOT USE `gets()` use `fgets()` instead, because `gets()` cannot prevent buffer overflow.

Comment: @iharob okay, next time i will use fgets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you open a file with `fopen`, the output you write is *buffered*, meaning it's not actually send to the lower layers until the buffer is either full or you explicitly flush it with `fflush`.

Also note that the layers under `fopen`/`fprintf`/`fclose`, all the way down to the actual hardware, may *also* have some buffering that can delay the actual update of the on-disk data.

Comment: Question is before `fclose` appear , where all intermediate data stored , here ,  i take input in q2[] and writing it to the file using `fprintf` but after `fclose` encounter then only new data will reflect onto file.

Comment: @uditr043 In a private and hidden buffer, that is flushed when the buffer is full, when you explicitly call `fflush` or you close the file with `fclose`.

Comment: Is the size of buffer is large enough to handle lots(hundreds) of data in a row before 'fclose' appear ? Like in this example if i want to enter more & more data in a single loop , will that be okay ? I test it with 8 records continuously and it's fine.

Comment: @uditr043 No it's not very large, usually just a few kilobytes. But it will be fine, because Like I said, when the buffer is full, it's flushed just the same way as you doing `fflush`, and the buffer is them emptied to be filled up again.

Comment: @ Joachim Pileborg Okay, thnx :)